# Get a class as javax.lang.model.element.Element in junit tests

Tags: java, class, testing, annotation-processing

I would like to test my utility class ElementUtils but I don't know how to get a class as an Element. In AnnotationProcessors I get my elements by using the following code

```
Set<? extends Element> elements = roundEnvironment.getElementsAnnotatedWith(annotation);
```

but since the RoundEnvironment is not available in the tests this is not an option.

Is there any way to get a class as an javax.lang.model.element.Element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a JUnit @Rule to invoke a compiler run during the test, at which point you may then use Types and Elements utility classes to obtain TypeMirror and Element instances.

Such a rule has been created and is a part of http://github.com/google/compile-testing and can be used thusly:

```
public @Rule CompilationRule rule = new CompilationRule();
private Elements elements;
private Types types;


@Before
public void setup() {
  elements = rule.getElements();
  types = rule.getTypes();
}

@Test void testStuff() {
  TypeElement typeElement = elements.getTypeElement("some.fully.qualified.ClassName");
  // do stuff.
}
```

Some of what stuff you can do to manipulate (whether in tests or otherwise) TypeMirror and Element instances can be found in the http://github.com/google/auto project in the common sub-module, which contains utilities for managing these java.lang.model classes conveniently.

Comment: I hear that `@Rule` is a JUnit 4 construct that does not work in JUnit 5 anymore.

Answer (score 1):

`Element` instances are only valid mid-compile.  The docs for [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/lang/model/element/Element.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) state that "the identity of an element involves implicit state", which in the `javac` implementation is actually invalidated once compilation is completed.  So, if you're trying to hold references to `Element` instances and compare them to other `Element` instances in a test, it's not going to work.

That said, you *do* have some flexibility if you cast a `javax.tools.JavaCompiler.CompilationTask` to a `com.sun.source.util.JavacTask`.  Then, you can manually invoke the `parse()` and `analyze()` phases and get at `Element` instances using the `Elements` instance returned from  `JavacTask.getElements()`.